# Manually installing CRAN to access xtable library

Tags: r, cran, xtable

I tried installing CRAN into R using

`install.packages("cran")`

The code would run but in the console the following message would appear

```
  package ‘cran’ is not available for this version of R
```

How can I install cran on my version of R?

Comment: CRAN is not a package, it is the main repository for R package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRAN is a repo not package, have you tried this:

```
install.packages("xtable",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Answer (score 1):

Better still just type `install.packages("xtable")`

Comment: perhaps explain the difference from the accepted answer (i.e., this approach will use a previously selected repository or pop up a selection box asking you to pick a CRAN mirror from a list ...) ?